# passing arguments to a command run by su

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

I want to run a command as a different user (the current user is root). Thus, I do

```
su newuser -c 'mkdir "/tmp/test"'
```

but I have a problem in passing arguments to it

```
i="name"
su newuser -c 'mkdir "/tmp/$i"'
```

or in a script

```
su newuser -c 'mkdir "/tmp/$1"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that inside single quotes, variable expansion is disabled. Inside double-quotes it is enabled. See e.g. [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) for more insight.

So, you can try to change your `su` call as follows:

```
i="name"
su newuser -c "mkdir '/tmp/$i'"
```

Since the argument to `su` is now in double quotes, the `$i` will be expanded because the single quotes are (to the interpreting shell that will pass the ultimate result to `su`) simply "text" and not special anymore.